# Assigning a value for each string in a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random number and then assigning that value to a day of the week in a list.

What I want to happen is if the value that is picked is "0" I want to print SUNDAY once (0 + 1 times). If its "1" i want it to print SUNDAY (then the next line) MONDAYMONDAY (1 + 1 times) and so on. See this picture for a complete example.

[image]

**Update:**

This code has been tried:

```
import random 
Random = random.randint(0, 6) 
dayList = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] 
for dayList in Random(0): 
    print "Sunday" * 2
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far. Also, can you give a credit to the exercise book you are working through?

Comment: You could start with generating the random number. That doesn't sound too hard.

Comment: Looks like you need two `for` loops. So where's the problem?

Comment: Combine `random.randint`, a `for` loop and string multiplication, i.e. `"Sunday" * 2` gives `"SundaySunday"`

Comment: `mult_dict = {mult: (mult+1, day) for mult, day in enumerate(['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'])}; number = int(input('Enter a number: ')); print('\n'.join([day*mult for i, (mult, day) in mult_dict.items() if i <= number]))` :)

Comment: I need to start with a random number generator and then create a list of the days of the week. Each value in the number generator needs to create a unique string of text. I just do not know how to use For loops and how to set one up with this specific problem. thanks!

Comment: So you know about for loops? There must be some code you could show us. Please update your question with everything you have. Check the above comments, there's lots you could do to update the question.

Comment: import random
Random = random.randint(0, 6)

dayList [
    'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
    ]

for dayList in Random (0):
    print "Sunday" * 2

Comment: This is what I have so far

Comment: Are you able to update the question while it is on hold? We want to get your code into the question, not languishing in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that satisfies the requirements:

```
import random 

dayList = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] 

def day_of_week(value):
    return dayList[value] * (value + 1)

def print_script(value):
    print('The number is', value)
    for v in range(value + 1):
        print(day_of_week(v))

value = random.randint(0, 6)

print_script(value)
```

And just to test all possibilities:

```
for v in range(7): 
    print_script(v)
```

Output:

```
The number is 0
Sunday
The number is 1
Sunday
MondayMonday
The number is 2
Sunday
MondayMonday
TuesdayTuesdayTuesday
The number is 3
Sunday
MondayMonday
TuesdayTuesdayTuesday
WednesdayWednesdayWednesdayWednesday
The number is 4
Sunday
MondayMonday
TuesdayTuesdayTuesday
WednesdayWednesdayWednesdayWednesday
ThursdayThursdayThursdayThursdayThursday
The number is 5
Sunday
MondayMonday
TuesdayTuesdayTuesday
WednesdayWednesdayWednesdayWednesday
ThursdayThursdayThursdayThursdayThursday
FridayFridayFridayFridayFridayFriday
The number is 6
Sunday
MondayMonday
TuesdayTuesdayTuesday
WednesdayWednesdayWednesdayWednesday
ThursdayThursdayThursdayThursdayThursday
FridayFridayFridayFridayFridayFriday
SaturdaySaturdaySaturdaySaturdaySaturdaySaturdaySaturday
```